# Softlayer estimated invoice doesnot contain ResourceId

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Question is why for assets like guest_storage we do not get all the information from API response for estimated invoice [API used: 'BillingItem' 'getNextInvoiceChildren']. E.g. The resourceTableId is missing altogether in the estimated billing invoice json.

**Json dump for estimated invoice:**
**For guest storage:**
Estimated bill id:  185101227

*Billing API dump:*

```
{'modifyDate': '2019-03-01T19:28:37-06:00', 'recurringMonths': 1, 
'id': 293978447, 'setupFee': '0', 'recurringFee': '0', 'lastBillDate': '2019-03-01T19:28:37-06:00', 
'nextBillDate': '2019-03-31T23:00:00-06:00', 'createDate': '2018-04-06T20:33:41-06:00', 
'oneTimeFeeTaxRate': '0', 'laborFeeTaxRate': '0', 'parentId': '', 'cancellationDate': '', 
'cycleStartDate': '2019-03-01T19:28:37-06:00', 'description': 'Image Template Storage', 
'laborFee': '0', 'oneTimeFee': '0', 'setupFeeTaxRate': '0', 'categoryCode': 
'guest_storage', 'allowCancellationFlag': 1, 'serviceProviderId': 1, 'orderItemId': '', 
'nextInvoiceChildrenCount': 0, 'recurringFeeTaxRate': '0'}
```

**On the other hand, we have the information in some cases**

***For hardware Asset:***

Estimated bill id:  185470395

***Billing API dump:***

```
{'modifyDate': '2019-03-01T19:26:56-06:00', 'resourceTableId': 1163849, 
'hostName': 'dal02sl12ibm015', 'recurringMonths': 1, 'id': 195858725, 
'setupFee': '0', 'recurringFee': '405', 'lastBillDate': '2019-03-01T19:26:56-06:00', 
'nextBillDate': '2019-03-31T23:00:00-06:00', 'createDate': '2017-07-04T01:53:23-06:00', 
'oneTimeFeeTaxRate': '0', 'laborFeeTaxRate': '0', 'parentId': '', 'cancellationDate': '', 
'cycleStartDate': '2019-03-01T19:26:56-06:00', 'description': 
'Dual Intel Xeon E5-2620 v4 (16 Cores, 2.10 GHz)', 'laborFee': '0', 'oneTimeFee': '0', 
'setupFeeTaxRate': '0', 'categoryCode': 'server', 'allowCancellationFlag': 1, 
'serviceProviderId': 1, 'orderItemId': 222901003, 'domainName': 'ibmbhfmgmt.local', 
'nextInvoiceChildrenCount': 26, 'recurringFeeTaxRate': '0'}
```

***Asset API dump for hardware asset :***

```
[{'datacenter': {'name': 'dal12'}, 'memoryCapacity': 64, 'provisionDate': '2017-07-04T04:18:03-06:00', 
'hardwareStatus': {'status': 'ACTIVE'}, 'tagReferences': [{'usrRecordId': 6862893, 'resourceTableId': 1163849, 
'tagId': 2504017, 'tagType': {'keyName': 'HARDWARE', 'description': 'Hardware'}, 
'tag': {'internal': 0, 'id': 2504017, 'name': 'backup:idera server', 'accountId': 9373713}, 'id': 129847405, 
'tagTypeId': 1, 'empRecordId': ''}], 'id': 1163849, 'fullyQualifiedDomainName': 'dal02sl12ibm015.ibmbhfmgmt.local'},....]
```

Comment: I seems that the billing item "185101227" does not have a resource attached, that's why it does not show you the "resourceTableId".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One of the cases I opened from control.softlayer.com said: "Ancillary services, add-ons, storage, etc do not need/have a resourceTableId simply because the system was designed this way". I will proceed with both the inputs and see if I get stuck anywhere.